# How to hide top default toolbar bar from the installed PWA?

Tags: browser, vuejs3, progressive-web-apps, vite, manifest.json

***Problem statement :*** After installed PWA as a standalone application, It is showing a toolbar at the top of the application which contains few controls. I want to hide this toolbar at all whenever user launch/use the application.

[image]

***What did I tried so far ?***

I tried the below solutions (in `manifest.json` file) given in the existing Stack Overflow questions but none of them worked for me.

- Tried all the `display` property values `standalone`, `fullscreen` and `minimal-ui`.
- Tried `display_override` property as well with this configuration.

  ```
  {
    "display_override": ["fullscreen", "minimal-ui"],
    "display": "standalone"
  }
  ```
- Tried by adding a `?fullscreen=true` param in the `start_url`.
- Tried `window-controls-overlay` in `display_override`.

  ```
  {
    "display_override": ["window-controls-overlay"]
  }
  ```
- Tried these configurations with multiple browsers but every browser having this toolbar at the top.

***As per the Chat GPT (I am not sure about the truthiness of this) :***

> Starting from Chrome 76 and later versions, the browser UI elements,
> including the top bar with the title, menu, etc.. are always displayed
> when launching a PWA, regardless of the display mode specified in the
> `manifest.json` file.
>
> This change was implemented to ensure transparency and provide users
> with a consistent browsing experience. As a result, it is not
> currently possible to hide the browser UI elements when launching a
> PWA.

I also tested these popular and branded web applications [`makemytrip.com`](https://www.makemytrip.com/), [`starbucks.in`](https://www.starbucks.in/dashboard) by installing in my laptop as PWA to see the `behavior` and they are also having same app toolbar at the top with those controls. So I am assuming that there is no way to remove that app controls toolbar ?

I am running PWA (application stack is `Vue 3 + Vite`) on `Windows 10` and Installed it as a chrome app (Chrome browser version is `117.0.5938.88`).

Is there any solution/workaround to hide this top toolbar permanently? Or while launching the app it should launch in full screen by default.

Comment: hi, are you manage to figure this out?

Comment: @dhee No, I think it’s a default feature of PWA and we don’t have a control to remove it. If you will find anything please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround which may help:
Launch the browser with a flag and url

- Chromium (same for chrome afaik):
  `path/to/chromium --app=https://link.com`
  This works almost exactly like a pwa [more flags here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).
- Firefox:
  `firefox --kiosk --new-window https://link.com`
  Firefox launches it in the same window if `--new-window` isn't specified, `--kiosk` launches it without extra controls in full screen mode, though new tabs can be created in the same window with shortcuts `Ctrl+T`.
  More flags can be found via `firefox -h`.

`--kiosk` and `--new-window` work for chromium, but not brave. Feel free to try it out for yours.

Hope it helps :)